# magento 2 swap firstname and lastname in shipping and billing address in diplay

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 how to swap firstname and lastname in shipping and billing address in diplay for the logged in customer in dashboard section. in default saved address ,i need to swap in display level only in frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your admin a then:

**Stores > configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > in options go to Address Templates**

there you can edit the template that displays the addresses in Front End area :)

Just disable **Use system value**

And edit according to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much,,saves my time..but it was not swapped in checkout page shipping address for logged in user how to do that?

Comment: Got idea for it ...Anyway Thanks again...

Comment: Oh man, checkout is another problem... Thankfully you only need to swap name and lastname :P

For checkout you need to overwrite the following:

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html**

and

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html**

In your custom Module

Comment: Yeah Got it thank you so much for your quick response